# How to number lemmas according to theorem counter

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am using a llncs.csl template to write a paper. And I want to do the following numbering for lemma:

Theorem 1, Lemma 1.1, Lemma 1.2, Theorem 2, Lemma 2.1, Lemma 2.2

The template use `\spn@wtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}`

Can you please help me how i can make changes in templete so it can number lemma according to theorem number.

Comment: If the Theorem environment is called `theorem`, then you might try this: `\spnewtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[theorem]{\bfseries}{\itshape}` and then you can do `\begin{lem}...\end{lem}`. However, we can probably provide more help if you are able to produce a minimal working example, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: I've removed the `biblatex` tag as it is not relevant for the question

Comment: I tried useing \spnewtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[theorem]{\bfseries}{\itshape}  but it give me error "Missing \begin{document}. \spn@wtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[theorem].."

Comment: Also I am using lncs format (Springer) template

Answer (score 3):

You could just redefine the `lemma` counter.

```latex
\documentclass{svjour3}

\counterwithin{lemma}{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Another lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Another lemma
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where I have to put this lemma redefinition? I have springer template which has these lines                                                                                
\spn@wtheorem{case}{Case}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
%\spn@wtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}

Comment: @TaniaMalik You place the `\counterwithin{lemma}{theorem}` line before `\begin{document}`